# How do I auto increment my results in a page?

Tags: python, django

I made this table but I can't figure out how to do the numbering. I want a top 10 list and I get all the data from a database. I essentially want to make it show '1' and the next '2' and the next '3' and so forth. How would I able to do this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMX1m.jpg

def home(request):
    straatData = data.objects.all()[:10]

```
count = data.objects.count()
numbers = []

for dataCount in range(1, count + 1):
    numbers.append(dataCount)

context = {
    'data': straatData,
    'count': numbers,
}

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

I need to get the top numbers to show 1,2,3,4... as many as the results. But I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set a context variable for that. You can use  `forloop.counter` in your template code.

```
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
   <td> {{ foorlop.counter }} </td>
   <td> {{ item }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to start counting at 0, use `forloop.counter0`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be using jinja to render the table in a loop?

In your html:

```
{% for num in count %}
<tr>
   <td> {{ num }} </td>
   <td> {{ data[num][0] }} </td>
   <td> {{ data[num][1] }} </td>
   <!-- Im not sure how your data is formatted! -->
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Without seeing your html it's hard to know how you're currently rendering the table.